# multivariate student-t regression

Tags: multivariate-regression

(1) I want to do a multivariate regression in R (where each output sample is a vector, instead of a number), which I know can be handled using the lm() function; however, the multivariate output data is not necessarily normally distributed, so I'm trying to use multivariate t regression as an alternative. Does that sound ok?

(2) Is there a package in R to do multivariate student-t regression?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the multivariate output data is not necessarily Normally distributed," or why you think that is important.

Comment: **where each output sample is a vector, instead of a number** is not clear? Do you mean continuous variables? R package mvtnorm may be used for multivariate regression.

Comment: (2) is off-topic and (1) would probably need more details to be answerable, so voting to close